# android compressing folder

Tags: android

I am doing a simple android application which consists of compressing folder. Actually the compression process is completed and the file is saved in the defined location. But the problem is when i push the zipped file from the emulator and unzipping it manually the files are corrupted. What's the problem. Is the file become  corrupted when we unzip manually?

My folder structure is given below

TestPlay1- contains two sub directories - playlist and content
the directory playlist contains a xml file
the directory content contains files such as images and videos

My code is given below

```
String zipFile = "/mnt/sdcard/Testplay1.zip";
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
updata = new ArrayList<File>();
contentpath = new File(FOLDER_PATH);
try {
    if (contentpath.isDirectory()) {
        File[] listFile = contentpath.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                File[] contfile = listFile[i].listFiles();
                for (int j = 0; j < contfile.length; j++) {
                    updata.add(contfile[j]);
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(contfile[j]);
                    zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(contfile[j].getName()));
                    int length;
                    while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        zos.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    }
                    zos.closeEntry();
                    // close the InputStream
                    fis.close();
                }
            }
        }
        zos.close();
    }
    System.out.println("Testplay1 Folder contains=>" + updata);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

Comment: You should consider using Apache Compression librairies. No need to re-invent any of these common operations.. http://developer-tips.hubpages.com/hub/Zipping-and-Unzipping-Nested-Directories-in-Java-using-Apache-Commons-Compress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use Zip4j: http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/

 There you can just put the Folder to compress and the rest is done by the library

```
ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile("/mnt/sdcard/bla.zip");
ZipParameters parameters = new ZipParameters();
parameters.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE);
parameters.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL);
zipfile.addFolder("/mnt/sdcard/folderToZip", parameters);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply .. can you please tell me the usage. i downloaded the zip file for eclipse work space. then what to do with this zip file? plz help me.

Comment: Unpack it and copy the jar file to the "libs"-Folder of your Android project